# How to display title of dialog in multi line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Suppose I have a dialog which is opened from java file . I want to set multiline title of these dialog box.

```
  dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.issue_attachment_preview);     
  String title=getString(R.string.previewImageDialogTitle)+"\n ["+attachment.filename+"]";
  dialog.setTitle(title);
  dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

But it does not display title in multiline , please suggest me any usable link or example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

immediately after calling `super.onCreate` and just before `setContentView`.

Then add the multiline textview on top of your dialog layout which will work as title

Answer (score 10):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
tv.setSingleLine(false);
```

Comment: This works good, should be accepted answer as it keeps all the other features of the title.

Comment: Just to note that if your dialog extends an AppCompatDialog then you need to be careful where you put this code. I had it in onCreateDialog of a DialogFragment, which was working fine until v23.2.1 of the support library, when it suddenly started throwing a "Window feature must be requested before adding content" exception. The solution was to move it to an event later in the lifecycle, such as onStart.